# how to manage image size for all iphone sizes using autolayout

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, autolayout, constraints

I am working an iOS app using autolayout.Please refer my screenshot below.I want to manage my image in all iphone and ipad(small size for iphone and big size for ipad)[image].What type of constraints i should apply.

Comment: First: Define what it should look like in the different screen size and orientation, Second: Define what changes, what doesn't. Third With the previous answers, above the screen at all, what define it (left border, right border, height, top, bottom, ratio? fixed? proportional? etc.) Then you'll have your constraint. But without that work on your side, it's hard to tell. I'd go with only with top, leading and trailing to superview, and fixed height (or ratio).

Comment: Why don't you add leading, top and aspect ration with same

Comment: @Larme Thanks,if I am applying fixed height means,It will be same for all devices right?

Comment: A fixed height means that it will be the same whatever the height of the screen it. A ratio would mean that it will keep the same ratio for the height according to your width (for instance, a iPhone 5 and iPhone Plus doesn't have the same width). You can manage between Phone/Tablet, but you need to do some work explaining how it should look like in others screens sizes (because it's clearly unclear), and then we can really help you.

Comment: Does your app supports All orientations? How it should be displayed in iPhone & iPad? Probably you need Top, Leading, Trailing equal to superview & height - aspect ratio.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the same height in all devices you can set the top, the leading and trailing constraints, then the "equal height" to the superview and change the multiplier to 0.3 like in the image:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[image]Yes, you can apply **Aspect Ratio** constraint to UIImageView to its own.

Answer (score 0):

To resize image view ratio-wise you need to give following constraints.

- Leading, trailing, top to super view
- Aspect ratio to image view

So as width increases, height will also be increases with ratio.

Comment: Trailing +  Aspect ratio and leading + trailing and Width constraints will cause break the constraint, Only required constraint is Leading and Top with aspect ratio to itself

Comment: Trailing constraint is also required otherwise image view might go beyond its superview bounds or may have less width with respect to its superview. As per given image in question, image view should stick its leading and trailing position to its superview.

Comment: Agree but if you provide aspect ratio it won't go because according to device width image with will be reduced !!

Comment: Just see this... https://imgur.com/a/5wd0jqt you may get the point what I'm trying to say.

Comment: To get it working you just need to assign the image  to image view !! !! :)

Comment: what if image is 1200x1000?

Comment: Whatever size of image you have doesn't matter , It is totally dependent on Imageview size  and that you are fixing up with Aspect ratio try it by your self

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173071/discussion-between-mahendra-gp-and-prashant-tukadiya).

Answer (score 0):

Follow below steps:-

- Set Equal height UIImage to UIView.
- Change multiplier which is in Attribute Inspector by click on Equal Height constraint.